# how to set more than one cookie in sveltekit endpoint response?

Tags: javascript, cookies, sveltekit

I'm using sveltekit set-cookie in an endpoint but I'm unable to figure out how to set more than one cookie. I get three cookies back from expressjs server. I need to set the three of them in my endpoint.

I have this endpoint in sveltekit that fetch from an expressjs

```
import cookie from 'cookie';
export async function post (event) {
    
    const info = await event.request.json()
      let email = info.name
      let password = info.password
      let fetchresults = ""
    
  //fetch from expressjs//
const letscookie = async () => {
      
      let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/testcookie',{
            method: 'POST',          
            credentials : 'include',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
           
          },
           body: JSON.stringify({
               username : email,
               password : password
           })
      }) 

      const data = await res.json()   
      fetchresults = data
      return data   

    } 
    let cookieresults = await letscookie()


  return {
  headers : {
      "loginjs-cookieone" : fetchresults.accesstoken,
       "loginjs-cookietwo" : fetchresults.refreshtoken,
      "x-custom-header": "Whatever",          
      'set-cookie': cookie.serialize("loginjs", " setcookie_in_loginjs_headers")    
  },     
  body : {
       //passthistofront,
       //results,
       cookieresults
      
  }
```

}

```
}
```

My question is how to setup more than one cookie in my headers? if I do

```
headers : {
          "loginjs-cookieone" : fetchresults.accesstoken,
           "loginjs-cookietwo" : fetchresults.refreshtoken,
          "x-custom-header": "Whatever",          
          'set-cookie': cookie.serialize("loginjs", " setcookie_in_loginjs_headers"),
'set-cookie' : [cookie.serealize("cookieone", "valueone"), cookie.serealize("cookietwo", "valuetwo")]  
      },
```

I get the last cookie set and anything before it is ignored or over written.
So how do I set more than one cookie in my headers using set-cookie?

Comment: I believe [they'd all be separate entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#the_set-cookie_and_cookie_headers) like so: https://pastebin.com/raw/VQn6rkEt

Have you already tried this?

Comment: When I put them on separate lines like I wrote in my question, I get an error :An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name and the last cookie is the only one that gets set. In my question code, the only cookie that is set is : cookietwo valuetwo

Comment: Check out https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#:~:text=To%20set%20multiple%20cookies%20simultaneously%2C%20return%20an%20array%3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed other set-cookie lines.
Just one set-cookie and put the cookies in an array like this

```
'set-cookie' : [cookie.serealize("cookieone", "valueone"), cookie.serealize("cookietwo", "valuetwo")]
```

One set-cookie in headers.